# "flutter run" not showing all devices that "flutter devices" shows

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, ios-simulator, flutter-run

I am following this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-boring-to-beautiful#0) with Flutter (fresh installation). Android Studio is also installed (fresh installation).

Here is the output of `flutter devices`

```
sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
Windows (desktop)       • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1766]
Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114
Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.44
```

The output of `flutter run`

```
Multiple devices found:
Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1766]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.44
Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q"): q
```

Is there a reason flutter run does not show my emulated device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check emulator device, you need to use

```
flutter emulators
```

Then to lunch specific emulator device

```
flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>
```

now to run on emulator device you can use

```dart
flutter run -d <emulator id>
```

While the emulator is open, `flutter run` might auto select the emulator device for most case.

If you are on android studio just select after creating device

[image: img]

More about [run on emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)

Comment: Thanks for that. All my previous searches failed to brink up "flutter emulators" at all.

Comment: Glad to help you out. You can also check [test-drive](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive)